CMake copy files when they change
I'm writing a CMakelists.txt. For one on my target FOO, I have to copy and paste shader files to the bin dir. Currently, I have done a POST_BUILD command
add_custom_command( TARGET FOO POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory               ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} COMMENT "Copying shaders" VERBATIM )
The issue, when I edit this file, if the target FOO is already build, the copied shader files are not updated. What can I do ?
I tried add_custom_target and add_dependencies but I don't understand the syntax.

Same problem here. I see this solution with add_custom_command everywhere, but nobody mentions that it copies files just once.. Even when i delete all copied files.
